# Linked list implementation in C

Tags: c, linked-list, memory-management, pointers

I'm learning C for mainly for fun and to get a better understanding of how things work under the hood (most of my experience lies with high-level languages). I've been following quite a few books and working through the exercises. For extra practice, I've implemented a linked list using the knowledge I've learned - I thought it might be useful to get some feedback on it!

I plan to make this generic and work with any type once I learn how to do this :)

I desire any and all feedback. Especially feedback that pushes me in the right direction (except for 'give up'!)

llist.h:

```
#ifndef __llist_
#define __llist_

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define LLMSG_ELISTNULL "List cannot be NULL"
#define LLMSG_EHEADNULL "Head cannot be NULL - list corrupted"
#define LLMSG_ENODENULL "Node cannot be NULL"
#define LLMSG_ENEWNULL  "New node cannot be NULL"

typedef struct _llist_node {
  struct _llist_node *next;
  int value;
} llist_node;

typedef struct _llist {
  struct _llist_node *head;
} llist;

/* 
   constructors & destructor
*/
llist_node *llist_node_create(int value);
llist *llist_create(llist_node *head);
void llist_destroy(llist *list);

/*
  insertion
*/

llist *llist_append(llist *list, llist_node *node);
llist *llist_prepend(llist *list, llist_node *node);

llist_node *llist_insert_after(llist_node *node, llist_node *new);
llist_node *llist_insert_before(llist *list, llist_node *node, llist_node *new);

/*
  removal
*/

llist *llist_remove_head(llist *list);
llist_node *llist_remove_after(llist_node *node);
llist *llist_remove(llist *list, llist_node *node);

#endif
```

llist.c:

```
#include "llist.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>

llist_node *llist_node_create(int value) {
  llist_node *node = malloc(sizeof(llist_node));
  if (! node) {
    errno = ENOMEM;
    return NULL;
  }

  node->value = value;
  node->next = NULL;

  return node;
}

llist *llist_create(llist_node *head) {
  assert(head != NULL && LLMSG_ENODENULL);

  llist *list = malloc(sizeof(llist));
  if (list == NULL) {
    errno = ENOMEM;
    return NULL;
  }

  list->head = head;
  return list;
}

void llist_destroy(llist *list) {
  assert(list != NULL && LLMSG_ELISTNULL);

  // do not proceed if list container corrupt
  if (list->head != NULL) {
    llist_node *head = list->head;
    llist_node *next;
    llist_node *next_next;

    // free rest of list first
    if (head->next != NULL) {
      next = head->next;
      while (next != NULL) {
        next_next = next->next;
        free(next);
        next = next_next;
      }
    }

    if (head != NULL) {
      free(head);
    }
  }

  free(list);
}

llist *llist_append(llist *list, llist_node *node) {
  assert(list != NULL && LLMSG_ELISTNULL);
  assert(node != NULL && LLMSG_EHEADNULL);
  assert(list->head != NULL && LLMSG_EHEADNULL);

  llist_node *next;

  if (list->head->next == NULL) {
    list->head->next = node;
  }
  else {
    for (next = list->head->next; next != NULL; next = next->next) {
      if (next->next == NULL) {
        next->next = node;
        break;
      }
    }
    assert(next->next == node && "Failed to insert node to end of list");
  }

  return list;
}

llist *llist_prepend(llist *list, llist_node *node) {
  assert(list != NULL && LLMSG_ELISTNULL);
  assert(node != NULL && LLMSG_ENODENULL);
  assert(list->head != NULL && LLMSG_EHEADNULL);

  llist_node *head = list->head;
  list->head = node;
  node->next = head;

  return list;
}

llist_node *llist_insert_after(llist_node *node, llist_node *new) {
  assert(node != NULL && LLMSG_ENODENULL);
  assert(new != NULL && LLMSG_ENEWNULL);

  llist_node *next = node->next;
  node->next = new;
  new->next = next;

  return new;
}

llist_node *llist_insert_before(llist *list, llist_node *node, llist_node *new) {
  assert(list != NULL && LLMSG_ELISTNULL);
  assert(node != NULL && LLMSG_ENODENULL);
  assert(new != NULL && LLMSG_ENEWNULL);

  llist_node *curr = list->head;
  while (curr->next != NULL) {
    if (node == curr->next) {
      curr->next = new;
      new->next = node;
      break;
    }
    curr = curr->next;
  }

  return new;
}

llist *llist_remove_head(llist *list) {
  assert(list != NULL && LLMSG_ELISTNULL);

  llist_node *head = list->head;
  if (list->head->next) {
    list->head = list->head->next;
  }
  free(head);

  return list;
}

llist_node *llist_remove_after(llist_node *node) {  
  assert(node != NULL && LLMSG_ENODENULL);

  if (node->next != NULL) {
    llist_node *delete = node->next;
    node->next = node->next->next;
    free(delete);
  }

  return node;
}

llist *llist_remove(llist *list, llist_node *node) {
  assert(list != NULL && LLMSG_ELISTNULL);
  assert(node != NULL && LLMSG_ENODENULL);

  llist_node *curr = list->head;
  while (curr->next != NULL) {
    if (node == curr->next) {
      curr = llist_remove_after(curr);
      break;
    }
    curr = curr->next;
  }

  return list;
}
```

linked-list.c (test output for each operation):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "llist.h"

int main() {
  llist *list = llist_create(llist_node_create(1));
  list = llist_append(list, llist_node_create(2));
  list = llist_append(list, llist_node_create(3));

  printf("1: %d\n", list->head->value);
  printf("2: %d\n", list->head->next->value);
  printf("3: %d\n", list->head->next->next->value);

  list = llist_prepend(list, llist_node_create(-1));

  printf("1: %d\n", list->head->value);
  printf("2: %d\n", list->head->next->value);
  printf("3: %d\n", list->head->next->next->value);
  printf("4: %d\n", list->head->next->next->next->value);

  llist_insert_after(list->head->next, llist_node_create(400));

  printf("1: %d\n", list->head->value);
  printf("2: %d\n", list->head->next->value);
  printf("3: %d\n", list->head->next->next->value);
  printf("4: %d\n", list->head->next->next->next->value);
  printf("5: %d\n", list->head->next->next->next->next->value);

  llist_insert_before(list, list->head->next->next, llist_node_create(500));

  printf("1: %d\n", list->head->value);
  printf("2: %d\n", list->head->next->value);
  printf("3: %d\n", list->head->next->next->value);
  printf("4: %d\n", list->head->next->next->next->value);
  printf("5: %d\n", list->head->next->next->next->next->value);
  printf("6: %d\n", list->head->next->next->next->next->next->value);

  list = llist_remove_head(list);

  printf("1: %d\n", list->head->value);
  printf("2: %d\n", list->head->next->value);
  printf("3: %d\n", list->head->next->next->value);
  printf("4: %d\n", list->head->next->next->next->value);
  printf("5: %d\n", list->head->next->next->next->next->value);

  list = llist_remove(list, list->head->next->next);

  printf("1: %d\n", list->head->value);
  printf("2: %d\n", list->head->next->value);
  printf("3: %d\n", list->head->next->next->value);
  printf("4: %d\n", list->head->next->next->next->value);

  list->head = llist_remove_after(list->head);

  printf("1: %d\n", list->head->value);
  printf("2: %d\n", list->head->next->value);
  printf("3: %d\n", list->head->next->next->value);  

  llist_destroy(list);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks good.

---

```
#ifndef __llist_
```

Avoid using leading underscores: [they are reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/49942).

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>
```

Code which includes your `llist.h` therefore includes `<stdlib.h>` etc., which makes compilation slower. Put as little as you can in your public header file; you could include those in your `llist.c` instead.

---

```
typedef struct _llist_node {
  struct _llist_node *next;
  int value;
} llist_node;

typedef struct _llist {
  struct _llist_node *head;
} llist;

/* 
   constructors & destructor
*/
llist_node *llist_node_create(int value);
llist *llist_create(llist_node *head);
```

Continuing to minimize the contents of the header file, you can use an "[opaque pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C)" (a.k.a. "handle" a.k.a. "cheshire cat") by declaring the following instead ...

```
struct llist_node;

struct llist;

/* 
   constructors & destructor
*/
struct llist_node *llist_node_create(int value);
struct llist *llist_create(struct llist_node *head);
```

... and define the structs in your C file. After all, client code doesn't/shouldn't need to know what's inside your structs.

To do that you would also need another function to get the value out of a node:

```
int llist_node_read_value(struct llist_node *node); // implemented as return node->value
```

Maybe an opaque pointer is 'overkill' in this simple example but it's a useful technique:

- Less in the header file makes it easier for clients to understand the public API
- Less in the header file makes it harder for clients to poke into private details (e.g. writing into your data structures
- May avoid recompiling client code when/if the layout/content of your struct changes (e.g. if your module is shipped as a static- or dynamic-linked library)

---

```
llist_node *llist_insert_after(llist_node *node, llist_node *new);
llist_node *llist_insert_before(llist *list, llist_node *node, llist_node *new);
```

I understand why one needs a `llist *list` parameter and the other doesn't, but it looks odd.

In llist_insert_after you don't check that node is on a list. When you add a created node to the list you assume that its `next` pointer is null.

However your API allows user code to do:

```
llist_node *first = llist_node_create(1);
llist *list = llist_create(first);
llist_node *second = llist_node_create(2);
llist_node *third = llist_node_create(3);
// this works even though second isn't a member of a list
llist_insert_after(second, third);
// this works badly because second->next is not null
llist_insert_before(list, first, second);
```

---

I don't understand why llist_append and llist_prepend return a pointer to llist instead of a pointer to llist_node.

---

```
void llist_destroy(llist *list) {
  assert(list != NULL && LLMSG_ELISTNULL);

  // do not proceed if list container corrupt
  if (list->head != NULL) {
    llist_node *head = list->head;
    llist_node *next;
    llist_node *next_next;

    // free rest of list first
    if (head->next != NULL) {
      next = head->next;
      while (next != NULL) {
        next_next = next->next;
        free(next);
        next = next_next;
      }
    }

    if (head != NULL) {
      free(head);
    }
  }

  free(list);
}
```

It's better to avoid/delay declaring a local variable until (later) the moment when you can first assign a value to it; so, the following would be clearer:

```
void llist_destroy(llist *list) {
  assert(list != NULL && LLMSG_ELISTNULL);

  // do not proceed if list container corrupt
  if (list->head != NULL) {
    llist_node *head = list->head;

    // free rest of list first
    if (head->next != NULL) {
      llist_node *next = head->next;
      while (next != NULL) {
        llist_node *next_next = next->next;
        free(next);
        next = next_next;
      }
    }

    if (head != NULL) {
      free(head);
    }
  }

  free(list);
}
```

---

Your list_remove methods silently do nothing (instead of loudly failing) if they fail to remove the requested node.

Consider coding your `void llist_destroy(llist *list);` function as `void llist_destroy(llist **list_ptr);` instead, so that its last statement can be `*list_ptr = 0` to try to ensure that the user/caller can't try to use (dereference) the list memory after it has been freed.

---

> linked-list.c (test output for each operation):

Your testing could be a bit more thorough, for example:

- Remove enough elements to completely empty the list and then verify that you can add more
- Destroy an empty list and destroy a non-empty list
- Append after one element in the list and prepend before one element in the list
- Decide whether you want to detect user errors (e.g. inserting a null pointer) and if so test that

---

Your use of messages like LLMSG_ELISTNULL in assert functions was new to me (I hadn't seen that before).

---

You don't have any methods to do anything useful with the list: for example, to search the list to see whether it contains a specific value.

Comment: I'm not sure that `llist_prepend()` and `llist_append()` require a return value at all. If the "instance" of `llist` being modified is provided, doesn't it not matter if a return to the list's node or the list itself is returned at all?

Comment: Returning a pointer to the newly-created node lets the caller do things to that node (e.g. subsequently delete the node from the list).

Comment: One more question. Where the program is checking for memory errors does it make sense to return `NULL`? Doesn't that put the impetus on the programmer to then deal with that error? Instead, shouldn't the program exist because none of the functions that follow adequately handle a Node or List with a `NULL` entry?

Comment: It makes sense to check for errors, because when errors are detected 'as soon as possible' that's makes them easier to debug. When a library finds an error, returning an error value (e.g. NULL) is problematic if (and only if) the calling program doesn't test for that error value: and that's a reason why C++ supports throwing exceptions instead. I don't have time for a good, long answer. I suggest you post a question on Programmers.SE and/or ask about this in [the Chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

Answer (score 4):

**Making it type-generic**

The key to making it generic is in the ll add function.  This should take the size of the object you want to add, and a pointer to the data member:

`llist_node *llist_node_create(void * pData, uint size);`

And then the implementation becomes:

```
typedef struct llist_node { pNext, char data[1] };
llist_node *llist_node_create(void * pData, uint dataSize)
{
    // -1 so you don't waste a byte of memory when copying over
    llist_node * pNewNode = malloc(sizeof(llist_node -1) + dataSize);
    memcpy(&pNewNode->data, pData, dataSize);
    return pNewNode;
}
```

This relies on whatever is calling the library knowing about the type/size of data object.

**Encapsulation**

Also, if you want to increase encapsulation, implement a `void * llist_GetDataElement(llist_node * llistEle);` function. This means you can hide the implementation details (i.e. the internal structure of your llist_node), and hence you could easily change it over to say, a fixed array, as opposed to malloc, based implementation etc.